# How can i adapt this code to reset the colour of past selected rows

Tags: javascript

How can I adapt this code so that when the row is selected the color changes but also resets anything else that has been clicked back to the original color. Obviously right now it changes the rows colour every click and all past selected rows colours stay the same.

```
var tr = document.getElementById("r_row" + r);
for (var c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerText = cellText[c];
    tr.appendChild(td);

    //Makes the rows selectable

    tr.onclick = function(event) {
        selectedItem = this;
        selectedItem.style.background = "#828891";

    }
}
```

Comment: Just a hint, give every row an unique index, then onclick, see if current row index != previous row index, if so, make it red and make every other default (with a loop)

Comment: Rather than using `style.background = "828891"` use `classList.add('selected');` In this case `selected` would be a class you defined in your css. Create all other `td` instances with an `unselected` class and you can loop through them with `document.getElementsByClassName()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative is to add a class, i.e `selected` and check for a selected `TR` using a collection of the selectable TRs.

```js
var trs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[id^="r_row"]'));
trs.forEach(function(elem) { 
  elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
    trs.forEach(function(tr) {
      if (tr !== elem) tr.classList.remove('selected');
    });
    
    this.classList.add('selected');
  });
});

function addTRs(ids) {
  var columns = 3;
  ids.forEach(function(r) {
    var tr = document.getElementById("r_row" + r);
    for (var c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
      var td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerText = `This is a test - ${r}`;
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
  });
}

addTRs([1, 2]);
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: #828891;
}

tr {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id='r_row1'></tr>
    <tr id='r_row2'></tr>
    <tr>
      <td colSpan='3'>Not selectable!</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```